# allow only one or some email extension

Tags: php, ajax

I just want to ask how can i allow *@abc.co.uk* or *@def.com.tr* or something else email extenssions. when user register my website ?

Like if user try to register with *(name@hotmail.com)* then this email is not allowing. But if user try to register with (*name@abc.co.uk or @def.com.tr)* then user can register the website.

```
$("#email").change(function() 
{ 

var email = $("#email").val();
var msgbox = $("#estatus");

if(email.length >= 3)
{
$("#estatus").html('<div class="checking">Checking availability...</div>');

$.ajax({  
    type: "POST",  
    url: "check_mail.php",  
    data: "email="+ email,  
    success: function(msg){  

   $("#estatus").ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings){ 

   var d = msg;
var str=msg.substr(0, 2);

    $("#estatus").html('');
    if(str == 'OK')
    { 
        $("#email").removeClass("no");
        $("#email").addClass("yes");
        //msgbox.html('<font color="Green"> Ok </font>  ');
    }  
    else  
    {  
         $("#email").removeClass("yes");
         $("#email").addClass("no");
         msgbox.html(msg);
    }  

   });
   } 

  }); 

}
else
{
 $("#email").addClass("no");
$("#estatus").html('<div class="error">Enter a valid e-mail</div>');
}



return false;
});
```

**PHP** *check_mail.php*

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
include_once 'includes/db.php';
include_once 'includes/Sc_Script.php';
$Sc = new Check_Email();
if(isSet($_POST['email'])){
   $value=$_POST['email'];
   // Check the mail is already in using or not
   $check=$Sc->Login_Check($value,0);
   if($check) {
      echo '<div class="error">'.$value.' = This email address is already in use.</div>';
    } else {
        // Else continue
        echo 'OK';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: You need a white list where you define what is allowed and then compare the input with it  to see if its allowed or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to pull out the domain and then you need to check that it is contained within some whitelist array:

```
function isDomainAllowed($email_address)
{

  $domain = substr($email_address, strrpos($email_address, '@') + 1);

  if (in_array(strtolower($domain), array(

    'abc.co.uk',
    'def.com.tr',

  )))
  {
    return TRUE;
  }

  return FALSE;

}

if (isDomainAllowed($email_address))
{
  // Allowed
}

else
{
  // Not allowed
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have check each & every whitelist domain with the supplied email.

```
$emailList = array();
$emailList = ["abc.in","def.uk"];
$flag = false;
foreach($emailList as $email)
{
    if(stripos($_POST['email'],$email) != false)
        $flag = true;
}
if($flag == false)
     echo "Invalid email domain";
```

Comment: What if the email address is `aabc.in@hotmail.com`?

Comment: In the `$emailList` array, you have define the whitelist of domains. Only those will be allowed.

Comment: Except the above will allow `aabc.in@hotmail.com`.